# Mapping to a tuple of values in a factory function explanation

Tags: python, class, dictionary, mapping, tuples

I came across the code snippet in Mastering Object-oriented Python.

I don't understand the syntax of line 2. I understand that rank_str is a dictionary. What is the `class_,` syntax and what is it doing?

The other part I don't understand is on line 8. If class_ is a class then why is `suit` needed in the constructor when it is never referred to? Is it because the *Card classes have it as a parameter in their constructors?

```
1. def card( rank, suit ):
2.    class_, rank_str= {
3.        1:  (AceCard,'A'),
4.        11: (FaceCard,'J'),
5.        12: (FaceCard,'Q'),
6.        13: (FaceCard,'K'),
7.        }.get(rank, (NumberCard, str(rank)))
8.    return class_( rank_str, suit )
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special syntax.  `class_` is just a variable.  It will wind up referring to one of the classes `AceCard`, `FaceCard`, or `NumberCard` because of the call to the dict's [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method.  So `class_(rank_str, suit)` is just like calling `AceCard(rank_str, suit)`, or `FaceCard(rank_str, suit)` or `NumberCard(rank_str, suit)` (depending on which class is chosen for the given input).

The assingment on line 2 is just like `a, b = 1, 2`.  It is assigning two variables in one assignment.  (The two values are taken from the dict.  You can see that every value in the dict is a tuple of two elements.)

> If class_ is a class then why is suit needed in the constructor when it is never referred to? Is it because the *Card classes have it as a parameter in their constructors?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

The values in the unnamed dictionary are all tuples of two values. If `rank` matches one of the keys in it, the variables `class_` and `rank_str` will each be assigned the corresponding tuple value. If not, then they will be assigned the `NumberCard` class and `str(rank)` — so those are the defaults.

Lastly, the`card()` function then returns the result of calling the class assigned to the `class_` variable and passing it the current values of `rank_str` and `suit` as arguments.